# Issue with batch for statement

Tags: batch-file

Really need some help with this, I've created a batch file to clear the content of old SEP definitions, i managed to get this to work but now the last for statement is asking for more?

I cannot see why its doing this, it looks completed yet its still asking - running from cmd (removing the extra %) and straight from a batch is just doesn't work.

**definfo.dat content**

```
[DefDates]

CurDefs=20141001.002



    cd C:\currentdefs
    for /f "skip=1" %%H IN (definfo.dat) do @set cver=%%H
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in ("%cver%") do set var1=%%j
    for /d %%i in (“C:\currentdefs\*") do if /i not "%%~nxi"=="%var1%" del /s /q /f "%%i"
```

Answer (score 2):

if this is your actual code, you have a problem with a typographical quote sign: `“C:\currentdefs\*"` compare the opening and closing quotes!

Comment: That's actually solved it, I've been pulling my hair out for hours looking at this thinking I'm going insane. Thank you ths.